# InvalidApnsCredential while sending notification over GCM

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

Since yesterday (21.2.2018) we receiving InvalidApnsCredential while sending push notification to ios devices over GCM. We checked certificate base on https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs and both certs (for development and production) are valid until feb/2019.. 
I'm curious if something changed on GCM side .. couldn't find anything plus we didn't change our server side.

Comment: ok .. not sure what you mean .... Based on documentation I shout upload certificate (.p12) to FCM ... But we are using GCM and don't want to move to FCM yet.

Comment: two certificates can expire here: __1.)__ your APNs certificate or __2.)__ your SSL; so it is worth to check both.

Answer (score 0):

So after email conversation with google support I have to transfer project to firebase (without changing server app.).

1. On the console ([enter link description here](https://console.firebase.google.com/)), select 'Add project'.
2. Click on 'Project name' drop-down.
3. Select the project configured with GCM.
4. Click on 'Add Firebase'.

Then recreate .p12 file based on these steps : [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)